# Using a Flex AIR application with the Flash browser plugin

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have a Flex AIR application. During the compilation process, a .swf file is generated. Is this SWF usable with the Flash browser plugin? If not, how would one go about porting the application to the browser? Are there pitfalls to be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common/standard approach is to create multiple projects in your IDE. Note that some AIR classes cannot be used in web applications. So you'll likely need to segregate the AIR specific code anyway.

You'll put the majority of your common code into shared libraries (SWC's). You might have several library SWC's (some might contain AIR only code, and vice versa). You also create two application projects: an AIR application and a web application.

The two application projects use the shared library SWC's and generally do not have much code in them. These are just "application shells" that utilize the common code from the SWC.